# Show Date Ending on the group and Chart Crystal Reports

Tags: date, crystal-reports

I have a Crystal Reports that is pulling data by date range and grouping it by WEEK. Also the data is displayed in Chart.  Everything works fine. However, I run in into one problem.

When I group by WEEK, it displays the start date in both grouping and chart. I would like to display the END Date. I wrote a formula to take care of this, however, for some reason the dates are off:

```
totext(cdate(dateadd("d",6,date({CallDate}))),"MM/dd/yyyy")
```

For example, I do a date range between 11/10/2013 - 11/23/2013. If I run this without a formula it groups like this:

> 11/10/2013
>
> 11/17/2013

I want to display

> **11/16/2013**
>
> **11/23/2013**

If I run this with the formula above, I get the following output:

> 11/20/2013
>
> 11/27/2013

I'm not even sure how they formula calculates 20 and 26. Any suggestions on how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a little tricky. CR assumes Sunday to be the first day of the week, unless specified otherwise. So, for example to get the first day of the week is Monday (number 2 in the default CR week), this formula will give you the first day of the week:

```
If DayOfWeek({@Today}) = 2 Then
{@Today}
Else If DayOfWeek({@Today}) = 3 Then
dateadd ("d",-1,{@Today})
Else If DayOfWeek({@Today}) = 4 Then
dateadd ("d",-2,{@Today})
Else If DayOfWeek({@Today}) = 5 Then
dateadd ("d",-3,{@Today})
Else If DayOfWeek({@Today}) = 6 Then
dateadd ("d",-4,{@Today})
Else If DayOfWeek({@Today}) = 7 Then
dateadd ("d",-5,{@Today})
Else If DayOfWeek({@Today}) = 1 Then
dateadd ("d",-6,{@Today})
```

To get you the last day of the week, which should be Sunday in a regular work week, this formula would give it to you:

```
If DayOfWeek({@Today}) = 1 Then
dateadd("d", +6, {@Today})
Else If DayOfWeek({@Today}) = 2 Then
dateadd("d", +5, {@Today})
Else If DayOfWeek({@Today}) = 3 Then
dateadd("d", +4, {@Today})
Else If DayOfWeek({@Today}) = 4 Then
dateadd ("d",+3,{@Today})
Else If DayOfWeek({@Today}) = 5 Then
dateadd ("d",+2,{@Today})
Else If DayOfWeek({@Today}) = 6 Then
dateadd ("d",+1,{@Today})
Else If DayOfWeek({@Today}) = 7 Then
{@Today}
```

So your days are:

Sunday (1)

Monday (2)

Tuesday (3)

Wednesday (4)

Thursday (5)

Friday (6)

Saturday(7)

So in your case, the formula to get the end date should be:

```
totext(cdate(dateadd("d",+6,date({CallDate}))),"MM/dd/yyyy")
```

Comment: I actually was able to group using formula I posted above. The only thing I added that fixed it was that it needed a Group Sort Export. Sort the date in ascending. Then the grouping works fine. The only problem left there is for example my data start on 11/06/2013 so the End Date should be 11/09/2013. It adds 6 days to it and the End Date for the first row is always start date + 6. I want it to be standard Sunday-Saturday.

Comment: Then you use my above formula. You check for DayOfWeek and then add accordingly to get to your Saturday.

Comment: Should I be replacing @Today with the CallDate field or actually today's date?

Comment: Replace it with the CallDate field. "Today" was just an easier example.

Answer (score 0):

Seems easier to convert the date to a week number value, then add the number of days you need to get to end of the week date.

[Modified from Source:](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1236836)

`dateadd("ww",datepart("ww",{Command.REPORTDATE})-1,date(year({Command.REPORTDATE}),01,01)-dayofweek(date(year({Command.REPORTDATE}),01,01)))+7`

Adjust the +7 at the end of the formula if you want the week to end on a different day.

[image: WeekEndingSaturday]

[Proof sample report](https://github.com/sunk818/crystal/tree/master/WeekEndingSat)